# Packing NuGet projects compiled in release mode?

Tags: nuget

Is there some way to make a NuGet package using code compiled in release mode? Or is there some reason I should only publish (make available locally, in this case) packages compiled in debug mode?

Every time I call `nuget pack` from my project directory, where I have the nuspec file below, on code I have only compiled in release mode, it complains about not finding the DLL in the debug folder (`"\bin\Debug\SomeProject.dll"`). If I compile it in debug mode, those files are there and it packs them up as it should.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>$id$</id>
        <version>$version$</version>
        <authors>$author$</authors>
        <owners>$author$</owners>
        <iconUrl>http://somewhere/project.png</iconUrl>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>$description$</description>
    </metadata>
</package>
```

Answer (score 234, accepted):

You can solve it like this:

```
NuGet.exe pack Foo.csproj -Prop Configuration=Release
```

([reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20150313044711/http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/262324))

Comment: For anyone who wants the short story from the link (good read, though), there was a change from v1.3 to v1.4 that goes from a default of Release to a default pulled from a project setting that can only be modified in the project file directly (no VS GUI option). To avoid the command-line property tweak for all future `nuget pack` calls, edit the project file XML in your favorite text editor.

Comment: Is there a way to package up both a Release and Debug version in one package and then have my project auto-use the Debug one vs. the Release one depending on if I'm in Debug vs. Release Solution configuration?

Comment: @JD: As far as I know it is not possible but I was thinking contributing that to nuget. Can you explain in which scenario would you need this feature? When will it be helpful?

Comment: If you simply want debug symbols for your package, you could either include your PDB files in the *.nuspec (e.g., `<file src="bin\Release\*.pdb" target="lib\net40\" />`) or [publish a symbols package](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-symbol-package) alongside your DLL package.

Comment: @J.D. I also want to package both Debug and Release，and I have found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37673692/how-to-create-a-nuget-package-with-both-release-and-debug-dlls-using-nuget-pack

Answer (score 18):

If you are using a post-build event and you want to create a package whether using Debug or Release configuration you can setup the post-build event commandline like so:

```
"<path to nuget tools>\NuGet.exe" pack "$(ProjectPath)" -Prop Configuration=$(ConfigurationName)
```

Answer (score 13):

To have NuGet automatically use Release mode when you run `nuget pack`, do the following:

1. Open your `.csproj` file in a text editor.
2. Find the following line:

   ```
   <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
   ```
3. In this line, replace `Debug` with `Release`.
4. Save changes.

Answer (score 2):

The answers here are good, but I was having a lot of problems with this for a .NET Standard project. I had a project that was only going to publish Release binaries, but it wasn't respecting my default build output path.

I added this to my CSProj which then enabled me to use the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6538786/3543437).

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
      <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)bin\$(PlatformTarget)\Release</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Chiming in here.
My build profile would build the DLLs to `bin\<arch>\Debug|Release`.
I was able to point to my folders by running the `nuget` command as follows:
Notice how I used the `-p` option.

```
PS > nuget pack -p Configuration="x64\Release"

Attempting to build package from ...
...

Found packages.config. Using packages listed as dependencies
...
- Add a dependency group for .NETFramework4.7.2 to the nuspec
Successfully created package...
```