# Custom nuget package with configuration framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I'm creating a private NuGet package for my company and I want to distribute two different versions of my `.dll`. The release `.dll` was for some developers who can call this dll for development. And the debug `.dll` id for some developers to develop the dll itself for the second version.

So my question is that if I wanted to accomplish this by using only **one** NuGet package, is this possible? Do I have to create a script on the installation of the package that adds references in the MSBuild, or am I overcomplicating things?

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I have to create a script on the installation of the package that adds references in the MSBuild, or am I overcomplicating things?

To my knowledge, you may overcomplicating this things. That means you want to use one `dll` for debug mode to test and another `dll` for release mode to develop, so **those two dll files should be independent**, which should be distributed to different packages. Because a NuGet package will normally hold just a single set of assemblies for a particular target framework. It is not really designed to ship a debug and release version.

Besides, when we publish nuget package, the release version of your `dll` is the best choice since users wont debug into your `dll`, they will only care about if it works fine and how it works.

In addition,  NuGet supports use any string as a suffix to denote a pre-release version, as NuGet treats any such version as pre-release and makes no other interpretation. So you can use `-beta` to specify a new version of that dll for develop.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning#pre-release-versions

Basically per my understanding, use a different version of the package should be better. Of course, if you persist on using one package, Nekeniehl provided the correct direction.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Yes, I may overcomplicating this thing, the idea to use beta nuget package is very well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the same dll and each team can get the dlls like `yournuget -release` or `yournuget -debug`.

I normally use a buildscript to create the nugets, [paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/) and [FAKE](https://fake.build/) will help you do the job.

And here a related answer to your question:
[How to create a nuget package with both release and debug dll's using nuget package explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37673692/how-to-create-a-nuget-package-with-both-release-and-debug-dlls-using-nuget-pack)

Comment: Thank you very much, according to the link, I can add debug and release dlls in one package. But just as Leo said, I may overcomplicating this thing. One more beta nuget package would be better. Anyway, also thanks your answer.