# Custom nuget package help needed

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, nuget-package, azure-artifacts

Hi I would like to know how I would go about this scenario:

- I have a .Net PCL library with Debug and Release configurations
- I want to create a nuget package out of it which holds both configuration outputs.
- I want to use VSTS as the symbols server for the Debug build.
- I want to switch to the correct assembly using selected configuration when having my package installed.

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37673692/how-to-create-a-nuget-package-with-both-release-and-debug-dlls-using-nuget-pack) but I
never got the targets file integrated into the consuming csproj file.
The version is set to a fixed number there?

This is my nuspec file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>My.Assembly</id>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <title>A Library</title>
    <authors>Me</authors>
    <owners>Me</owners>
    <!-- <licenseUrl>http://LICENSE_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</licenseUrl> -->
    <!-- <projectUrl>http://PROJECT_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</projectUrl> -->
    <!-- <iconUrl>http://ICON_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</iconUrl> -->
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>A Library</description>
    <releaseNotes>Some release notes.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2018</copyright>
    <!-- <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags> -->
  </metadata>
      <files>
        <file src="bin\**" target="lib" />
        <file src="*.targets" target="build" />
    </files>
</package>
```

What is advised to do here?

*(using NuGet Version: 4.4.1.4656)*

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can check if it help you. AFAIK, a NuGet package will normally hold just a single set of assemblies for a particular target framework. It is not really designed to ship a debug and release version. Normally you do not publish a debug and a separate release version of your application to end users. if you persist, you can check the workaround below.

Answer (score 1):

> but I never got the targets file integrated into the consuming csproj file.

Not sure why you could not got the targets file integrated into the consuming csproj file, if `.targets` file is under your build folder in your nuget package, then when you add this nuget package to the project, the `.targets` file will be integrated into the consuming csproj file.

**The first thing is make sure the nuget package is correct:**

This is my `.nuspec` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>My.Assembly</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Admin</authors>
    <owners>Admin</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2018</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\**" target="lib" />
    <file src="*.targets" target="build" />
  </files>
</package>
```

You should **make sure that `.targets` file is in the same folder as your `.nuspec` file**, in this case, this command `src="*.targets"` can include the `.targets` file into the nuget package.

**Note:** **The name of the .targets file must match the ID of your package**, for your situation, the name of .targets must be **My.Assembly.targets**.

After pack the `.nuspec`, you will get following structure nuget package:

[image]

Then install this package to your project, after installation, unload the project, edit the project file, in the `.csproj` file, following code would be imported:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\My.Assembly.1.0.0\build\My.Assembly.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\My.Assembly.1.0.0\build\My.Assembly.targets')" />
```

Now, the `.targets` file integrate into the consuming csproj file.

**In addition**, there is an issue for this solution, because the dlls in lib folder will be **automatically added as references** creating the following in the project file:

```
<Reference Include="My.Assembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\My.Assembly.1.0.0\lib\Release\My.Assembly.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

So we could not set dll file in the lib folder, we could set the dll file in to the tools folder, then add a target in the .targets file to copy the dll file from tools folder to lib folder before build the project:

```
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\My.Assembly.dll" target="lib\net\$(Configuration)\My.Assembly.dll" />  
    <file src="bin\**" target="tools" />
    <file src="*.targets" target="build" />
  </files>
```

For the detailed info you can refer to the Arie R`s answer in the thread which you are referencing:

[How to create a nuget package with both release and debug dll's using nuget package explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37673692/how-to-create-a-nuget-package-with-both-release-and-debug-dlls-using-nuget-pack/47030559#47030559)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer Leo! I already managed to get it working. I didn't know that assemblies from lib where the ones added as reference in the csproj, thanks. But I think content is a better place then. I'm struggling with the target frameworks now... I'll update my question when I make more progress.

Comment: @grmbl, could you post your solution as a answer and accept it after SO limitation? This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread. Thanks.