# How to create a nuget file with both the Release and Debug configurations using msbuild in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, nuget-package

I need to create a nuget file which contains both the release and debug versions of my dll. I need to be able to do this in Azure Devops using the MSBuild task.

I'm using MSBuild due to the bug in the NuGet Task where if you use the new packagereference and projectreference it doesn't do the dependency information correctly.

I have tried doing two builds one in debug and one in release, and then having the release one do a pack. This still only gave me one file. I also tried using a nuspec file to try to tell it to grab both files, but this still only resulted in one file in the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to create a nuget file with both the Release and Debug configurations using msbuild in Azure Devops

I am afraid you could not **create** a nuget file with both the Release and Debug configurations using **msbuild** at this moment.

That because NuGet package will normally hold just a single set of assemblies for a particular target framework. It is not really designed to ship a debug and release version.

If we use nuget, we could use a custom MSBuild `.targets` file in the `.nuspec` that has its own references and configuration information:

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37673692/how-to-create-a-nuget-package-with-both-release-and-debug-dlls-using-nuget-pack) for some more details.

But, if you want use the MSBuild, we could not specify the dlls file driectly, we have to create two packages for `debug` and `release`, then we add a custom MSBuild `.targets` file in the project file with the properties `<Pack>true</Pack>` and `<PackagePath>build\</PackagePath>`, like following:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="build\*.targets" Pack="True" PackagePath="build\" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

In this case, the `.targets` file will be packed in the build folder, which will imported into the nuget installation project:

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37673692/how-to-create-a-nuget-package-with-both-release-and-debug-dlls-using-nuget-pack) for some more details.

Besides, in the `.targets` file, you could use a `Choose/When` to select the `PackageReference` for `debug` and `release`:

```
<Choose>
    <When Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='debug' ">
        <ItemGroup>
            <PackageReference Include="MyRefDebug"> 
              <Version>1.0</Version> 
            </PackageReference>
        </ItemGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
        <ItemGroup>
            <PackageReference Include="MyRefRelease"> 
              <Version>2.0</Version> 
            </PackageReference>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Otherwise>
</Choose>
```

Check the [github ticket](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5895) for some more details.

Hope this helps.